# Cannot start secure DataNode due to incorrect config?

Tags: security, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, datanode

all principals are created with own keytabs,
.... REALM is HADOOP.COM. HOSTNAME is server.hadoop.com. ssh key are created, I copy the public_key to authorized_key, I gave it read and write for owner `chmod 600` . I used Unlimited JCE Extensions for encreption type AES-256. Also, I used JSVC to run datanode as root.

core-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
  <value>kerberos</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.rpc.protection</name>
  <value>privacy</value>
</property>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
 <name>dfs.replication</name>
 <value>2</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>/home/hdoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>/home/hdoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>

<!-- General HDFS security config -->
<property>
   <name>dfs.block.access.token.enable</name>
   <value>true</value>
</property>
<!-- NameNode security config -->
<property>
   <name>dfs.https.address</name>
   <value>server.hadoop.com:50470</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.https.port</name>
   <value>50470</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.keytab.file</name>
   <value>/etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.service.keytab</value> <!-- path to the HDFS keytab -->
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal</name>
   <value>hdfs/server.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.kerberos.internal.spnego.principal</name>
  <value>HTTP/server.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM</value>
</property>

<!-- secondaryNameNode security config -->
<property>
  <name>dfs.secondary.namenode.keytab.file</name>
  <value>/etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.service.keytab</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.secondary.namenode.kerberos.principal</name>
  <value>hdfs/server.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.secondary.namenode.kerberos.internal.spnego.principal</name>
  <value>HTTP/server.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM</value>
</property>

<!-- DataNode security config -->
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir.perm</name>
   <value>750</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.address</name>
   <value>0.0.0.0:1004</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
   <value>0.0.0.0:1006</value>
</property>


<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.keytab.file</name>
   <value>/etc/security/keytabs/dn.service.keytab</value>  <!-- path to the HDFS keytab -->
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.kerberos.principal</name>
   <value>dn/admin@HADOOP.COM</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.web.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
  <value>HTTP/server.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.web.authentication.kerberos.keytab</name>
  <value>/etc/security/keytabs/http.service.keytab</value>
</property>
```

hadoop-env.sh

```
# Set Hadoop-specific environment variables here.
export HDFS_NAMENODE_USER=hdoop
export HDFS_DATANODE_USER=hdoop
export HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER=hdoop


export HADOOP_OS_TYPE=${HADOOP_OS_TYPE:-$(uname -s)}
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64


export HADOOP_OS_TYPE=${HADOOP_OS_TYPE:-$(uname -s)}
export JSVC_HOME=/home/hdoop #here I have my commons-daemon-1.3.1-src
```